# cursor: pointer make only points clickable and not lines

Tags: highcharts

I am using a line chart with multiple lines in it.

The documentation specifies:

> cursor: String You can set the cursor to "pointer" if you have click
>   events attached to the series, to signal to the user that the points
>   and lines can be clicked.

I only want the points to be clickable and not lines. The problem I am facing is I have other lines (which dont have a point at that x axis value) overlapping my points. Selecting that point selects that overlapping line and that overlapping line's point. Thus in the onclick callback I get the value for the wrong point.

Any ways to fix this?

Comment: I can cook up a jsfiddle if anyone needs one.

Comment: Yes, a jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have clickable points on both series? Because if you don't have on the one that is overlapping than you will always end up clicking the right one and it won't really be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have clicks only on one series, set for that series highest z-index (series would be on top), see: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zIndex